# Maximum transaction size

Tags: plutus, cardano-node, transaction

As far as I know the maximum transaction size is 16kB including metadata https://github.com/cardano-foundation/CIPs/blob/master/CIP-0009/CIP-0009.md

However, I recently submitted successfully several transactions whose sizes are larger than 16kB (around 20kB). So I am a bit confused. Please help me clarify it.

Thanks

Comment: Please add Tx hashes or something we can query the chain with!

Answer (score 0):

The size corresponds to its representation on chain, not the file you are submitting directly.